# Prove $\forall_{y>0} \exists_{x \in I} [f(x) =y]$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I'm struggling to understand this proof. The question reads as:

> Consider the following formula, where f represents a function defined on an open interval $I$:
>   \begin{equation}
> \forall_{y>0} \exists_{x \in I} [f(x) =y]
> \end{equation}
>   Pick a value of $a$ so that the formula can be proved in the case when $I=(a, \infty)$ and $f$ is the function 
>   \begin{equation}
> f(x) = x+1
> \end{equation}
>   and prove the formula.

I chose $a$ to be equal to $-1$. Then the equation becomes:

\begin{equation}
 \forall_{y>0} \exists_{x \in (-1, \infty)} [x+1 =y]
\end{equation}

So my notes say that $\forall_{\alpha (x)} [\beta (x)]$ is an abbreviation of $\forall_{x} [\alpha (x) \Rightarrow \beta (x)]$.

And  $\exists_{\alpha (x)} [\beta (x)]$ is an abbreviation for $\exists_{x} [\alpha (x) \wedge \beta (x)]$

So according to me, the question is:
\begin{equation}
\forall_{y} [[y>0] \Rightarrow [ \exists_{x} [ [x\in (-1, \infty)] \wedge [x+1 = y]]]]
\end{equation}

Hopefully, I'm correct so far...

My proof below:

\begin{align}
    1&.\quad \quad \forall_{y} [[y>0] \Rightarrow [ \exists_{x} [ [x\in (-1, \infty)] \wedge [x+1 = y]]]] \\
    2&. \quad \quad y \tag{initialise}\\
    3&. \quad \quad y>0 \tag{1} \\
    4&. \quad \quad x=y-1 \tag{choose} \\
    5&. \quad \quad y-1 \in (-1, \infty) \tag{3} \\
    6&. \quad \quad x \in (-1, \infty) \tag{5} \\
    7&. \quad \quad x+1 = y-1+1 \tag{4} \\
    8&. \quad \quad x+1=y \tag{7} \\
    9&. \quad \quad [x \in (-1, \infty)] \wedge [x+1 = y] \tag{7,8} \\
    10&. \quad \quad \exists_{x} [ [x\in (-1, \infty)] \wedge [x+1 = y]] \tag{4 $\to$ 9} \\
    11&. \quad \quad [y>0] \Rightarrow [ \exists_{x} [ [x\in (-1, \infty)] \wedge [x+1 = y]]] \tag{3 $\to$ 10} \\
    12&. \quad \quad \forall_{y} [[y>0] \Rightarrow [ \exists_{x} [ [x\in (-1, \infty)] \wedge [x+1 = y]]]] \tag{2$\to$11}
\end{align}

There are a couple of things in my proof that doesn't make sense to me. First, in line two we initialise $y$. But then we assume that $y>0$, so I write that down again.

In fact, I don't really know what we are trying to prove.

It seems like we are trying to prove that every $y$-value, for $y>0$ has an $x$-value associated. But when I look at my proof, I don't see that at all.

Can somebody please help me identify what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:
Kavi Rama Murthy Pointed out that it would be better to choose $x$ as $y-1$. I think it makes sense to me now. Can somebody please verify my changes to the proof?

Comment: You are making things too complicated. All you need is $(a+1, \infty)$ containing  $(0,\infty)$ so the condition on $a$ is $a \leq -1$.

Comment: I don't exactly understand, sorry. The question says to pick a value for $a$. I picked $a = -1$ which conforms to your $a \leq -1$.

Comment: If you pick $a=-1$ you are alsmost done. For any $y>0$ take $x=y-1$ and see that this $x $ belongs to $(a, \infty)$ and that $f(x)=x+1=y$.

Comment: oof. That makes sense. Let me rewrite some things. Thank you.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I've updated my proof now. I think it makes more sense to me! Could you please verify?

Comment: Yes. Your proof is correct.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks! You're more than welcome to answer this question with your comments. I'll mark your answer as correct since you helped me understand it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your choice of $a$ is good. To complete the proof simply note that if $y>0$ and $x=y-1$ then $x\in (-1,\infty)=(a,\infty)$ and $f(x)=x+1=y$. This completes the proof.